# How can I install MySQL in termux?

Tags: mysql, termux

I want to install mysql in android turmux but it is not activating MySQL. It is showing error as

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have tried pkill command but didn't work how can I do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

Install the `maridb` package by running below command:

```
pkg install mariadb
```

To access root account, you need to login with Termux user name

```
mysql -u $(whoami)
```

Then try below commands:

```
use mysql;
set password for 'root'@'localhost' = password('YOUR_ROOT_PASSWORD_HERE');
flush privileges;
\q
mysqld_safe
```

I found the answer [Over Here.](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/MariaDB)

Comment: Thanks Ajay ! It woked I got my solution. I was searching for this past week